# Latent variable two time-point model

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, latent-variable, growth-model

I have a latent variable that was measured at 2 time points, and I want to model the growth in this latent variable. I then want to examine how variations in slope and intercept differ by  latent and non-latent covariates, allowing for interactions between these covariates as well. What is the best way to do this? I can't do a latent growth model because there are only 2 time points.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a latent growth model with two variables.

Example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lavaan)

d <- data.frame(y1 = rnorm(1000)) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(y2 = rnorm(1000) * y1 + 1)

model <- "
  int =~ 1 * y1 + 1 * y2
  slope =~ 1 * y2
  int ~~ int
  slope ~~ slope
  y1 ~ 0
  y2 ~ 0
  int ~ 1
  slope ~ 1
  y1 ~~ 0 * y1
  y2 ~~ 0 * y2
  
  "

fit <- lavaan::sem(model, d)
summary(fit)
```

Edit:

Here's the output which shows the slope and intercept variances.

```
Latent Variables:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
  int =~                                              
    y1                1.000                           
    y2                1.000                           
  slope =~                                            
    y2                1.000                           

Covariances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
  int ~~                                              
    slope            -1.049    0.059  -17.861    0.000

Intercepts:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
   .y1                0.000                           
   .y2                0.000                           
    int              -0.004    0.032   -0.113    0.910
    slope             1.022    0.047   21.543    0.000

Variances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
    int               1.043    0.047   22.361    0.000
    slope             2.251    0.101   22.361    0.000
   .y1                0.000                           
   .y2                0.000
```

Comment: Thank you, but in a latent growth model I can't get get an identified model with the variance of the slopes...I end up having a model where individuals differ on intercept but their slopes are all uniform. A plot of the data shows that there is considerable variation in slope, which I want to model somehow, but it's proving to be very difficult with only 2 time points. I'm looking for a different way to model the data that let's me model both variation in intercept and slopes even with just two time points.

Comment: The model I posted has variance in slope and intercept. I'll edit the answer, to include the output.

Comment: Thank you, I was indeed able to run the model you specified but the model fit is terrible. I am going to keep looking for models specifically designed for two time points. I think some form of latent change score model is what I need.

Comment: This is a latent change score model. If you specified it correctly it should have zero degrees of freedom, and the fit will be 0 (the model is just identified, fit is irrelevant).

Comment: Thank you I see now how the model you posted and a latent change score model are the same!